# Mysql[5.7] nested select query couldn't identify the parent table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Mysql 5.7 nested select query is throwing error when that

```
Unknown column 'CRoute.ID' in 'where clause'
```

This is my query

```
SELECT CTrip.ID, CRoute.Name, 
(SELECT COUNT(StudentID) FROM CRouteStudent WHERE CRoute.ID = CRouteStudent.RouteID) AS ExpectedStudents,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM CRouteStudent WHERE CRoute.ID = CRouteStudent.RouteID GROUP BY Stop)  as a) AS ExpectedStops
FROM `CTrip`
JOIN `CRoute` ON `CRoute`.`ID` = `CTrip`.`RouteID`
JOIN `CRouteSchedule` ON `CRouteSchedule`.`RouteID`=`CTrip`.`RouteID`
WHERE `CTrip`.`Direction` = '1'
LIMIT 30
```

ExpectedStudents is working, ExpectedStops throw error

**NOTE This query is working in the mysql 8.0**

Comment: Please describe the table too .

Comment: which table structure you need?? CRoute table is the root table and CRoute.ID is foreign key of CTrip, CRouteStudent tables as RouteID

Comment: please share create table queries, so that i can reproduce issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subqueries are nested to deep.

You can try to replace

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM CRouteStudent WHERE CRoute.ID = CRouteStudent.RouteID GROUP BY Stop)  as a)
```

with:

```
(SELECT count(DISTINCT stop)
        FROM croutestudent
        WHERE croute.id = croutestudent.routeid)
+
EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM croutestudent
               WHERE croute.id = croutestudent.routeid
                     AND stop IS NULL)
```

You can leave the `+ EXISTS ...` part away if `stop` isn't nullable.

Comment: do you know the reason?? Why this query doesn't support in 5.7 and working in the 8.0

Comment: @FazlanAhamed: I wrote the reason in the answer -- "The subqueries are nested to deep.".